# Get the value from dart's map

Tags: arrays, list, dart, getvalue

```
  var bob = {
    'A': 4,
    'B': [4, 5, 6, 7],
    'C': 6
  };
  print(bob['B'][2]);
}
```

i expect to get 6, but it case error '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'. how to get value from list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `{}` constructor create Map<dynamic, dynamic>, that's why compiler doesn't know what type is there. try cast `Object` to `List`, but don't forget to check type.

```
final bobB = bob['B'];
if (bobB is List)
  print(bobB[2]);
```

Comment: is right here. @bogdan1992 if you are sure it will always be `List<int>` at `bob['B']` then you can use ` var bobB = bob['B'] as List<int>;
      print(bobB[2]);`